# Are toxins being released when one sweats during sickness?

Tags: influenza, toxins, perspiration

I am getting over the flu that is prevalent in California right now.

The last two nights, I have awakened with my t-shirt quite wet. It seems as if I'm sweating rather profusely from my chest to my stomach. This did not happen the worst days of my illness, just these last two when I am close to being recovered.

My assumption (I am no expert in medical things, by any means, though) is that this is from toxins which are being eliminated from my system.

Is my assumption correct? If so, exactly which organs are the ones doing the toxin eviction?

Note: I have noticed this in the past during bouts of illness, too, but this time I am moved to ask about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually flu's are accompanied by fevers, when your internal thermostat is effectively 'reset' by the virus and your body temperature increases. When you're recovering, your internal thermostat is now resetting to its correct temperature so your body cools down. The way you cool down is by sweating. 
As for your question regarding detoxification, the kidney and liver are the main powerhouses for removing toxins. According to Donald Smith, a professor of environmental toxicology,(https://www.huffingtonpost.com/melissa-edmonds/does-sweating-release-tox_b_8372452.html), "Less than 1 percent [of toxins] are lost through sweat".